# Go to beginning of line without opening new line in VI

Tags: vim, vi

For ages now I've used <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> to move to the beginning and end of a line in `vi`.

However <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> is more for opening a new line above the cursor.

Is there any command which just takes you to the start of a line?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, type :help left-right-motions in Vim for plenty of info.

Comment: a good book for vim: practice in vim.
`^`
`0`

Answer (score 489, accepted):

You can use <kbd>^</kbd> or <kbd>0</kbd> (Zero) in normal mode to move to the beginning of a line.

<kbd>^</kbd> moves the cursor to the first non-blank character of a line
<kbd>0</kbd> always moves the cursor to the "first column"

You can also use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to move and switch to Insert mode.

Comment: Also Shift+A and Shift+I goes to end and beginning of line respectively and also switches to Insert Model

Comment: For me, pressing `^` is usually not as easy as pressing `0` and `w` consecutively.

Comment: ^ is easier to remember if you work a lot with regular expressions, but 0 actually while ^ doesn't (anymore) in vi in my Ubuntu bash terminal window

Answer (score 41):

A simple `0` takes you to the beginning of a line.

`:help 0` for more information

Answer (score 33):

Try this [Vi/Vim cheatsheet](http://worldtimzone.com/res/vi.html) solution to many problems.

For normal mode :
<kbd>0</kbd> - [zero] to beginning of line, first column.
<kbd>$</kbd> - to end of line

Answer (score 13):

You can use <kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>^</kbd> to move to beginning of the line.
And can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to move to the beginning and switch to editing mode (**Insert**).

Comment: You answer is mostly correct but there's a small caveat. `Shift+I` or `^` will move cursor to beginning of the **text** in the line. If line has `n` tabs in the beginning, it'll move cursor to `n*tabstop + 1`th column. While `0` moves cursor to the *very first column* of the line.

Answer (score 13):

There is another way:

```
|
```

That is the "pipe" - the symbol found under the backspace in [ANSI layout](https://deskthority.net/wiki/ANSI_vs_ISO).

Vim quickref (`:help quickref`) describes it as:

> ```
> N      |      to column N (default: 1)
> ```

#### What about wrapped lines?

If you have wrap lines enabled, `0` and `|` will no longer take you to the beginning of the screen line. In that case use:

```
g0
```

Again, vim quickref doc:

> ```
>  g0   to first character in screen line (differs from "0"
>       when lines wrap)
> ```

Comment: Now I see why it works. Thanks. I was wondering. I think it is better than `0` because `|` and `$` are on the same key.

Answer (score 13):

**Move the cursor to the begining or end with insert mode**

- `I` - Moves the cursor to the first non blank character in the current line and enables insert mode.
- `A` - Moves the cursor to the last character in the current line and enables insert mode.

Here `I` is equivalent to `^` + `i`. Similarly `A` is equivalent to `$` + `a`.

**Just moving the cursor to the begining or end**

- `^` - Moves the cursor to the first non blank character in the current
  line
- `0` - Moves the cursor to the first character in the current line
- `$` - Moves the cursor to the last character in the current line

Answer (score 7):

Type "^". And get a good "Vi" tutorial :)

Comment: It doesn't work in my vim if the line is indented. And `shift+0` mentioned above works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I just found 0(zero) and shift+0 works on vim.

Comment: `shift+0` that's `)` , which is next sentence

Comment: `Shift+0` is better, `^` shows the character and that's annoying. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>0</kbd> Takes you to the beginning of the line

<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> Takes you to the end of the line

Comment: Shift-0 (')') doesn't take you to the beginning of the line

Comment: Shift-0 (")") is "sentence forward" not "end of the line" (that's what I meant)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
:-0
```

This sets the cursor at the present line (blank here) at the 0 column.